# PrimeFaces autocomplete="off" didn't work for username and password

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using jsf 2.2 and PrimeFaces 5.0. problem is I have the system login page that is done 
by spring security, and also to add new user im using another page
which is shown below.

```
                 <tr>
                    <td><p:outputLabel value="User nameee : " for="user_name_test" /></td>
                    <td><p:inputText autocomplete="off" id="user_name_test" 
                            value="#{userController.userName}" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><p:outputLabel value="Password : " for="pass_word_test" /></td>
                    <td><p:password autocomplete="off" id="pass_word_test"
                            value="#{userController.password}" /></td>
                </tr>
```

the problem is that in chrome I just put the remember password to my system login page after that whenever I tried to use the username and password text in any form. it keeps getting fill by that user name and password. I tried to put the "autocomplete="off" in my register new user page. but it didn't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29582380/4462191 Possibly a duplicate of this

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't do anything about it JSF-wise as its remembered by the browser, but you can go to

```
chrome://settings/personal
```

and select "Show advanced settings" and manage the passwords under "Passwords and forms".